# "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true only colorizing one nesting level vs-code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to use "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled" but it seems to works only with one nesting level and keep the same color for all nested brackets.

[image]

I've tried to force the color manually but only affects the very first brackets pair.

[image]

I am using vs code for mac Version: 1.71.2 (Universal)! Someone here has faced the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Set `"editor.bracketPairColorization.independentColorPoolPerBracketType": false`.

It was set to true. Now it works as espected.

[image]